# Is it possible to draw the charcter partially in a cell rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, gdi

I'm working in WinForms application. In my scenario, i need to hide the text at beginning insteaf of last character when resize the cell rectangle.I can resolved this by removing the characters from first and draw it in rectangle.

Now i need to draw the character partially while resizing the cell rectangle. Please refer to the attached image. For example, the cell value is "20.229.88", after resizing the cell value should be "0.229.88", but "0" should be shown as partially.

[image]

Please anyone help me if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code which you're using ? Assuming it's GDI drawing (from your tags) you could set the StringFormat to right align the text withing the drawing rectangle.

Comment: If the text you're hiding is always in the same format you could experiment with putting something in front of it to hide the parts you don't want - think of a window where the glass shows the bit you want to see and the frame and wall hide the rest. Admittedly, in practice this might be difficult to do...

Comment: Hi @James , here is code , i have used to hide the text at beginning                        `string text = e.DisplayText; 
            SizeF size1 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, new Font(e.Style.Font.Facename, e.Style.Font.Size)); 
            while (!e.TextRectangle.Contains(new Rectangle(e.TextRectangle.Location, new Size((int)size1.Width, (int)size1.Height)))) 
            { 
                text = text.Remove(0, 1); 
                size1 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, new Font(e.Style.Font.Facename, e.Style.Font.Size)); 
            } 
            e.DisplayText = text;`

Comment: If you DrawString the text into a Rectangle it will be cut off. What control are you drawing on?

Comment: Hi @TaW, thanks for your suggestion. If i use DrawString method, i can cut the character which is at end of the text, but i need to cut the char at beginning. Please have look on attached image.

Comment: You should be able to do that by setting the Left of the Rectangle to a negative number.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code, because it will be easier for people to read. As you know how to use DrawString (suggested by @TaW ), I've added an answer to adjust the format which the method will output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a StringFormat object to the DrawString method, which sets the text to be right aligned within the rectangle, so then the left side gets cut off.

```
var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;

e.Graphics.DrawString("my text", this.Font, Brushes.Blue, new RectangleF(10,0,120,20), sf);
```